# Importing class from the root folder from a class in a package: unable to resolve class

Tags: groovy

I have the following directory/package structure in my groovy project:

```
src
 + progressManagers (package)
 |   |
 |   + LoadSensitiveProgressManager.groovy
 + TemporaryRegistry.groovy
```

Contents of TemporaryRegistry.groovy

```
// here is no package definition set
public class TemporaryRegistry {}
```

Contents of LoadSensitiveProgressManager.groovy

```
package progressManagers

// this gets marked red in my IDE (Intellij Idea)
import TemporaryRegistry

class LoadSensitiveProgressManager implements GenericProgressManager {
}
```

When i run my code in Scriptrunner for Jira Server the class is not found:

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
file:/data/atlassian/application-data/jira/scripts/progressManagers/LoadSensitiveProgressManager.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class TemporaryRegistry
@ line 7, column 1.
import TemporaryRegistry
^
1 error

Why is that?
I can "import TemporaryRegistry" from every groovy file in the src folder.

Thanks in advance
Jens

Comment: `TemporaryRegistry` is in the default package. Have you tried using it without importing it?

Comment: src folder must be in classpath

Comment: @ernest_k: without the import i get

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TemporaryRegistry for class: progressManagers.LoadSensitiveProgressManager
 at progressManagers.LoadSensitiveProgressManager.markFinished(LoadSensitiveProgressManager.groovy:58)
 at progressManagers.GenericProgressManager$markFinished$0.call(Unknown Source)
 at postFunctionDoImport.run(postFunctionDoImport.groovy:237)

Comment: @daggett: the src folder is marked as "sources root" in the IDE.
And on the Jira server the contents of the src folders (e.g. TemporaryRegistry.groovy) are located in the "scripts" folder of script runner which is the "script root".

If it was classpath issue would accessing the class from a script in the script root as well?

Comment: How are you referencing it for Groovy to give you a missing property exception?

Comment: @ernest_k im calling a static method on it
i have added the methods to the description to make this more clear